# How to have a QR Code take action on an already-open tab?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, qr-code

I've been searching SO looking for information about this, and cannot find any. We're building a QR Code-based in-store shopping experience for a local retailer, and our goal is to enable shoppers to scan a QR code that's associated with some item in the shop and thereby add it to their cart.

We are able to handle the logic associated with whether or not the user has already set up a cart and whether or not they're logged into the application, but the challenge we're facing is more of a user experience challenge: *each QR code scan, it seems, by default, will open a new tab in the person's mobile browser.*

### The Problem

When users are browsing a shop and adding items to their cart, each item that is added will cause a new browser tab to open. This is bad user experience, because if I go into the shop and add 5 items to my cart, I will now have 5 browser tabs open.

From my research, it doesn't seem like there's any way to get around this.

### Our Current Approach

Currently, we're handling the user's intention with query parameters that are baked into the QR Code. For example, an item that's in the store has a QR code that's associated with `...?item=1234&location=xyz`. Using these two parameters, `location` and  `item`, our React web application can handle the logic determining where the user is shopping and what item they'd like to add to their cart.

### Expected Behavior

Ideally, we would like for the browser to recognize that there is a tab open that's interacting with our web application, and then add the item to the user's cart *in the browser tab that's already open with their shopping cart*.

### Our Tech Stack

- React
- Next
- Web deployment via Vercel

I would love to hear any tips you have or knowledge you might share that would help make the user experience better for this use case.

Thanks!

Comment: There's nothing about scanning a QR code that of necessity opens a new browser tab. We have no idea from what you posted about how you implemented your application, so it's basically impossible for anybody to help.

Comment: Okay, I'll update the question with more details.

Comment: In theory... You have to check if a user is online when a new tab is opened. If yes - then just call `window.close()` using JavaScript when a new item has been successfully added to the cart (this will transform the user to a previously opened tab). And create some sort of a `setTimeout` JavaScript function on the main tab to check for newly added items. Not a really good solution, but may help.

Comment: Yes, that's an interesting thought, and a move in the right direction @rceman.

Comment: Any new ideas on this in the meantime? I’m looking for something similar.